# Why calling a Fragment in onCreateView()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an Activity with a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` includes 3 `Fragments`. They can change by a Swipe.

For Example:

1. FirstFragment + Swipe (right to left) = SecondFragment
2. SecondFragment + Swipe (right to left) = ThirdFragment
3. ThirdFragment + Swipe (left to right) = SecondFragment
4. ...

My Problems:

1. If I am on the FirstFragment. Just the FirstFragment and the
   SecondFragment call `OnCreateView`.

***How can I make that every Fragment call `onCreateView`?***

2. If I change from the ThirdFragment to the SecondFragment, the
   `onCreateView` of the FirstFragment is called.

***If I understand the Fragment lifecycle, I think at the moment I switch to the ThirdFragment the FirstFragment is calling the method `onDestroyView()`. How can I avoid that, so that everytime each Fragment is 'live'?***

I hope you can help me. Please be specific I am a beginner.

BR
Marco

Comment: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5)`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5)` works for me

Answer (score 0):

Using the Viewpager with  FragmentPagerAdapter keeps the fragments in in memory.

When you "load" for first time the fragment, will invoke OnCreate. But the second time Android will look into memory for it, so there is no need to call onCreate agian.

Take a look to the offical documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html